# Dynamic content overflowing parent div jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I've prepared a nice JFiddle for my issue. There is a button that allows you to add an element to a div. I want the div to have a scroll bar added to its vertical axis when it overflows, instead they just continue down the screen into nothing.

HTML

```
<button>Add</button>

<div id="foo">

</div>
```

CSS

```
p{display:inline;}
#foo{
background:#456;
height:200px;
width:100%
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    ii = 1

    $("button").click(function(){

            $("#foo").append("<div>"+ii+"&nbsp;&nbsp;<p class='remove'>Remove</p></div>")
            ii++

    })

    $("div").on("click","p",function(){$(this).parent().remove()});


})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/25kwG/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow:scroll`

```
#foo{
  background:#456;
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/25kwG/5/